# Download Azure read only function source code

Tags: python, azure-functions

I have Azure function app coded in Python. It seams that as it's running in linux it is in read-only mode and I can't change it. Is there way to download the source files to local folder. I need to edit the code and re upload it to Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

Also, you can go to the related storage of your function app, check the scm-releases container, and then you will find the zip file you deployed before.

Original Answer:

You can use ftp to get app content, but only premium plan and app service plan:

[image]

If you are based on the consumption plan, you need to click in each trigger and copy the code.

[image]

And the files outside the trigger is in this place:

[image]